# How to sum up user's input in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a program that reads integers from the user and adds them to a list. This ends when the user enters 0. The program then prints the sum on the list.

My code works but the problem is the sum value does not add up correctly

```
public class Main {
        private static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> test1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter multiple numbers"); //if user enters =0; loop ends


    while (input.nextInt() != 0) {
        test1.add(input.nextInt());
        input.nextLine();
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int x : test1){
        total+=x;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
}
```

Comment: And what happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing every third value in your loop. This

```
while (input.nextInt() != 0) {
    test1.add(input.nextInt());
    input.nextLine();
}
```

should be something like

```
int value;
while ((value = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
    test1.add(value);
}
```

or

```
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    int value = input.nextInt();
    if (value == 0) {
        break;
    }
    test1.add(value);
}
```

Comment: hey could u please explain how does that only store every 3rd value into the loop?

Comment: `input.nextInt()` reads an int. It doesn't put it back after reading it. So `while (input.nextInt() != 0)` that skips one. And `input.nextLine()` that skips another. So, for every three ints you entered, your code would only store one. Maybe you got lucky on `input.nextLine()` and it only skips half of the values.